# Pandas - return sum of keys from another DF

Tags: pandas

Trying to return a summed value based on keys from a second DataFrame.

For instance, take column 0 in df1:

```
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

And sum the matching values from column 1 in df2:

```
   0  1
0  a  4
1  b  3
2  c  2
3  d  1
4  e  7
```

to return a value of 9.  Values in column 0 in both DataFrames are non-repeating.

So far, other than a simple (and not at all Pandas-y) for loop, my best attempt is `result = df2.loc[(df2[0]==df1[0]), df2[1]].sum()`, which returns a "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" error.

I expect this is straightforward for those with more Pandas experience than I, but I'm Pooh-trying-to-leave-Rabbit's-house level stuck.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nearly there, try: `df2.loc[df2[0].isin(df1[0]), 1].sum()`. See: [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html). For [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) just pass the *label* (i.e. `1`, not `df2[1]`).

Comment: @ouroboros1 maybe I misunderstood what OP wants (I thought thet wanted to map values "*sum the matching values from column 1 in df2*"), in this case they maybe just want a groupby? I can reopen if you want

Comment: @ouroboros1 fair enough, I changed the duplicate

Comment: Correct; the goal was to return a single value.  I'm new enough to Pandas, though, that I did also appreciate the new rabbit hole to go down, @mozway; thanks much for that answer.

Much appreciated!  And heartening to see that I was at least in the ballpark.